# Extract the time part from a timestamp column in Hive

Tags: datetime, hive

I need to extract only the time part from a timestamp column (YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss) in Hive. Say if `my_timestamp` value is `2016-01-04 00:12:06` I need to get the time i.e., `00:12:06` from the timestamp.

I have tried

`concat(hour(my_timestamp),':',minute(my_timestamp),':',second(my_timestamp))`

and

`concat(hour(cast(my_timestamp as string)),':',minute(cast(my_timestamp as string)),':',second(cast(my_timestamp as string)))`

But not getting the output in required format.

Is there any other method to get only the time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the query:

```
hive> select substr('2016-01-04 00:12:06', 12)
    > ;
OK
00:12:06
```

Comment: Thank you for the query!! Getting the output in desired format.

Answer (score 4):

from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(event_time), 'HH:mm:ss')